MySQL updating column in record to NULL does not work?
I have this table with a before update trigger that prevents duplicate notes that have the same value in their hash column.
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_dupehash 
FROM notes 
WHERE hash IS NOT NULL AND (UPPER(hash) = UPPER(NEW.hash))
    
IF (UPPER(NEW.hash) IS NOT NULL) AND (UPPER(NEW.hash) <> UPPER(OLD.hash)) THEN
   IF (v_dupehash > 1) THEN
     signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = "Duplicate hash. Already have that note";
   END IF;
ELSEIF (NEW.hash IS NULL) THEN
   SET NEW.hash = NULL;
ELSE
   SET NEW.hash = UPPER(NEW.hash);
END IF;

My SQL statement is
UPDATE notes set hash = NULL WHERE ID = 5

The command runs with no errors.
When I check the table, the record still has a value in hash.
What's going on here? previously I had been using 'NULL' and then I saw that is incorrect, but the given solution is not working.
Google searches bring up everything about updating a NULL column so I'm stuck.
I can't see what I'm missing here.

Why use a trigger to enforce the hash column as unique and not simply use a unique constraint?

Provide complete sample according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

Do not use UPPER, set case-independent collation to the column instead.

There's no need to call UPPER() when checking for NULL.

ELSEIF (NEW.hash IS NULL) THEN SET NEW.hash = NULL; what's the point of setting it to what it already is?

IF (v_dupehash > 1) should be IF (v_dupehash > 0). Your code is checking for something that already has duplicates, which shouldn't be possible.

Don't you need to check that the duplicate is a different ID than the one you're updating?
